# wine themes don't affect apps installed via playonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I have changed the wine's theme but it affect only the apps installed via directly with wine, the apps installed via playonlinux are not affected, how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, PlayOnLinux creates a unique Wine prefix for each app installed through it, because of the fact that some programs require certain things to be installed and others not be installed, so the programs could create conflicts with each other. As a result, each of these Wine prefixes has its own config files. You would have to manually go into each prefix and change the theme for each prefix individually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you say where is located wine prefixes created by playonlinux? in ~/.PlaOnLinux directory?

Comment: If you open your home directory in nautilus, press Ctrl+h and you can view all hidden files. There should be a directory for PlayOnLinux. Remember to accept any answer you find helpful :)